# Apache mod_rewrite : double redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to mess with mod_rewrite since this morning, but I cannot achieve what I want.

Here is the problem...

I have the following file structure:

```
|
|_ virtual
| |_ app
|   |_ .htaccess
|_ real
  |_ app
    |_ index.php
    |_ .htaccess
    |_ javascript
      |_ app.js
```

Basically, what I want users to browse the site via the `/virtual/app` url. This access must add a parameter into the query string (in real project, there will be several folders like the virtual one, with different values for this parameter).

The .htaccess into the `real/app` folder redirects any query not pointing to an actual file, to the `index.php` file. Here is its content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So, here are some examples of redirections I want:

```
/virtual/app -> /real/app?p=1
/virtual/app/whatever -> /real/app/whatever?p=1
/virtual/app/javascript/app.js -> /real/app/javascript/app.js or /real/app/javascript/app.js?p=1
```

Could you help me to write the `virtual/app/.htaccess` file?
Thank you in advance.